# How to split string in sql server and put it in a table

Tags: sql-server-2008

My input is like

```
(abcd@123, xyz@324, def@567)
```

I want an output

```
col1   Col2
abcd   123
xyz    324
def    567
```

and so on

Column 1 should have `abcd` and `xyz`, and column 2 should have `123` and `324` both in different rows and so on. and the String can be of any size.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT LEFT('abcd@123', CHARINDEX('@', 'abcd@123')-1),
       RIGHT('abcd@123', CHARINDEX('@', 'abcd@123')-1)
```

Comment: Hi The answer is right but the string that i have, has an uncounted number of data, means that can have two data set or it can have 5 data set too, as i am fetching data from database. So could you please tell me how it will work when the data not fixed.

Comment: mmm ok, do you have a specific delimiter like the @ ?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `CHARINDEX()` and `SUBSTRING()` functions to split your input values.

Answer (score 1):

your actual problem is turning a complex String into a table i gues.
That for i found help with a procedure about 1 year ago, that does exactly that:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] (
@myString varchar(500),
@deliminator varchar(10))
RETURNS 
@ReturnTable TABLE (
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[part] [varchar](50) NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @iSpaces int
    Declare @part varchar(50)

    Select @iSpaces = charindex(@deliminator,@myString,0)
    While @iSpaces > 0
    BEGIN
        Select @part = substring(@myString,0,charindex(@deliminator,@myString,0))

        Insert Into @ReturnTable(part)
        Select @part

        Select @myString = substring(@mystring,charindex(@deliminator,@myString,0)+ len(@deliminator),len(@myString) - charindex(' ',@myString,0))
        Select @iSpaces = charindex(@deliminator,@myString,0)
    END

    If len(@myString) > 0
        Insert Into @ReturnTable
        Select @myString
RETURN
END
```

Create this procedure and you can do:

```
DECLARE @TestString varchar(50)
SET @TestString = 'abcd@123,xyz@324,def@567'
Select * from dbo.fnSplitString(@TestString, ',')
```

Result:

```
id|     part
1 |     abcd@123
2 |     xyz@324
3 |     def@567
```

this part you can combine with Leonardos answer:

```
SELECT 
LEFT(part, CHARINDEX('@', part)-1) As Col1,
RIGHT(part, LEN(part) - CHARINDEX('@', part)) As Col2
from dbo.fnSplitString(@TestString, ',')
```

to get your problem solved.

(little note: the function has little issues with whitespaces, so please try to avoid them there)